# concatenate files and remove source file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, centos

I have this command to concate files matching a pattern, but I do want to remove them, and I want to prevent the case when a file that just created should be just deleted (and no concatenation)

sample files names:

```
start-2014-03-25-08-08.log
scheduled-2014-03-19-13-03.log
scheduled-2014-03-19-14-58.log
```

command used

```
ls -1 | sed -r "s/(.*)-[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2})+/cat \1* >> \1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")/" | uniq | cat
```

output is:

```
cat start* >> start-2014-03-26-12-26.log
cat scheduled* >> scheduled-2014-03-26-12-26.log
```

but I do want to remove the files once they have been appended. Since the files are large, it could be a slight chance of delay that meanwhile appending a new "save pattern" file is created and I do not want to remove that one.

What would be the correct way?

**Update**

I have this now.

```
 rm -f temp.files;ls -1 *.log > temp.files; cat temp.files | sed -r "s/(.*)-[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2})+\.log/cat \1* >> \1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").log/" | uniq | sh; xargs rm -rf < temp.files; rm -f temp.files
```

Comment: I think it is best to create a temp file (or var or whatever) storing the list of files to be affected and then work with it, both for `cat` and `rm`.

Comment: You are attempting to append to a filename which would be matched by the `glob` that you've specified!  (This would cause the output file to be appended to itself.)

Comment: If I understand it correct your command appends but doesn't delete the files, or is it something else?

Comment: @devnull I think the command works ok now.

Comment: @Pentium10 I'd suggest that you delete the question if you don't have anything to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I had this:

```
 rm -f temp.files;ls -1 *.log > temp.files; cat temp.files | sed -r "s/(.*)-[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2})+\.log/cat \1* >> \1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").log/" | uniq | sh; xargs rm -rf < temp.files; rm -f temp.files
```

Answer (score 2):

No temporary files needed.

```
ts=$(date +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
for f in *; do
    prefix=${f%%-*}
    cat "$f" >> "$prefix-$ts"
    rm "$f"
done
```

Since it's possible for the loop to take more than a minute to run, I set `ts` outside the loop so that the same minute is always used. You can move that assignment inside the loop if you want different output files depending on when the concatenation actually takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Since you generated that `cat` command using `sed` and later pipe it to `sh`, you could modify the `sed` expression so as to instruct `sh` to delete the file if it was appended successfully, i.e., change the replacement expression to:

```
cat \1* >> \1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").log \&\& rm -f &
```

from

```
cat \1* >> \1$(date  +"-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M").log
```

Note that you need to escape the `&` in the replacement in order to produce the literal `&` and `&` by itself would be the entire match (the input filename in your case).

This would also obviate the need of `rm -rf < temp.files` in your command since every file would be removed after being appended.